# Calculate the weight of planet on drop downs and print it to input type

Tags: javascript, html

I have the code for a form with some drop down menus with different options in it and I have also create alert pop up message so that they cannot select same planet now. I also have disable one input on one textbox for input because I only can put one input.

My question is how do I calculate the weight of the planet based on the dropdown box I selected? And also print/ display it on the input type means if I select earth and my input type (weight) is 60N, if my second select is Venus it will calculate the weight for me and print / display it to input type.

Below is roughly my HTML code and JavaScript code. I'm new to JavaScript.

html :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
  <body>
   <select name="select1" id="select1" onchange="process_selection(this)">
 <option value="">-- choose one --</option>
   <option value="0">Earth</option>
   <option value="1">Venus</option>
   <option value="2">Mars</option>
  <option value="3">Jupiter</option>
  <input type="text" name="123" id="text1" 
    onchange="process_selection(this)" placeholder=""> N
 </select>
    <br>

    <select name="select2" id="select2" onchange="process_selection(this)"> 
 <option value="">-- choose one --</option>
  <option value="0">Earth</option>
   <option value="1">Venus</option>
  <option value="2">Mars</option>
   <option value="3">Jupiter</option> 

     <input type="text" name = "123" id="text2" 
     onchange="process_selection(this)" placeholder=""> N


  </select>
```

javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function process_selection(obj)
 {


var input1 = document.getElementById("select1").value;
var input2 = document.getElementById("select2").value;
var texta = document.getElementById("text1");
var textb = document.getElementById("text2");


if(input1 == input2)
{
    alert("Please select other planet");
}
 if(texta.value != "")
   {
     document.getElementById("text2").disabled = true ;

  } 
 if(textb.value != "")
 {
  document.getElementById("text1").disabled = true ;

 }

   // var xx = input1.options[input1.selectedIndex].value;
  var SurfaceGravityEarth = 1;
  var SurfaceGravityVenus= 0.907;
  var SurfaceGravityMars= 0.377;
  var SurfaceGravityJupiter= 2.364;
  var weight1 , weight2;
   // var sg1;
   //  var sg2;

  if (input1 == "0"  ) 
 {

weight1 = document.getElementById("text1") * SurfaceGravityEarth;
}

  if (input2 == "1"  ) 
  {
  weight2 = document.getElementById("text1") * SurfaceGravityVenus ;
  document.getElementById("text2").value= weight2 ;
  } 

}
```

I'm stuck at the calculation part.

Comment: what you get from `document.getElement('xxxx') ` is a DOM Element type. In this case , you cannot just do multiply on it,  maybe you need to use `document.getElement('xxxx').value` to get the value on that element, and then convert this string value to number type so that you can use it to do math work

Answer (score 1):

first, get the value of textbox and convert it to number type (integer, float etc). 
Try the following code:

```
weight1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("text1").value) * SurfaceGravityEarth;
```

use parseInt() to convert to integer type.
if you want to convert to float type use parseFloat()
or you can simply use Number() method for both integer and floating point numbers